# Csv parser - Evaluate header for each file

Tags: csv, parsing, header, copy, vertica

I have multiple CSV files in a directory. They may have different column combinations, but I would like to COPY them all with a single command, as there is a lot of them and they all go into same table. But the FDelimitedParser only evaluates the header row for the first file, then rejects all rows that do not fit - ie. all rows from most of the other files. I've been using FDelimitedParser but anything else is fine.

1 - Is this expected behavior, and if so, why ?

2 - I want it to evaluate the headers for each file, is there a way ?

Thanks

(Vertica 7.2)

Comment: So you have multiple sources and you try to load them all in the same target ? Can you explain better ?

Comment: My table has a defined set of columns. Columns in the files are subsets of this set, but each file can have a different subset and tens of different combinations can co-exist in directory.

Comment: Ok, But you have target tables for any of the files in the data/files landing area ? Correct ! And each csv/txt file with data has headers ?!

Comment: Excuse me I don't understand the question about target tables and landing area, could you reformulate ? And yes, each csv file has headers.

Comment: you have file* with (col1,col2,col3) and also a table with (col1,col2,col3), also file (col1) and table with (col1). For every type of file in the landing area you will have a table corresponding to it! is that true ?

Comment: Or you want multiple files with different columns to flow into a single table ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need flexTable for that , see http://vertica-howto.info/2014/07/how-to-load-csv-files-into-flex-tables/

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but I thought flex tables are used when the schema is unknown and/or columns will have to be added to the table. In my case, the superset of columns is known and declared - my issue is about parsing multiple files at once, of which columns are different subsets of my table's columns.

Comment: My understend from your input is  that you have flex input data ,you  can such flex input into flex table otherwise you need common csv files

Comment: A flex table puts everything into the raw column, tagged by column name, and then you either materialize out what you want or access it directly from the flex table (probably slower and bigger because it can't do column compression and other optimization).  I think what the OP is looking for, though, is to use a standard table and read the columns to populate out of the CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small workaround that I use when I need to load a bunch of files in at once. This assumes all your files have the same column order.

Download and run [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)

Navigate to folder with csv files

```
cd your_folder_name_with_csv_files
```

Combine all csv files into a new file

```
cat *.csv >> new_file_name.csv
```

Run a [copy statement in Vertica](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/COPY/COPY.htm) from new file. If file headers are an issue, you can follow instructions on [this link](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/48320-remove-first-line-all-files.html) and run through Cygwin to remove the first line from every file.